# Ansible escaping double quotes and single quotes

Tags: escaping, ansible, double-quotes, single-quotes

I would like insert a nrpe command in the nrpe.cfg with this ansible command

```
check_tomcat_threads.pl -H localhost -p 30011 -C '"http-bio-30011"' -w 200 -c 50
```

But the the problem are the '" and "'

To set this line in the nrpe.cfg use the command

```
 - { regexp: '^command\[SERVICE_tomcat_pi_Threads\]', line: "command[SERVICE_tomcat_Threads_pi]=/appiu/monitoring/check_tomcat_threads.pl -H localhost -p 30011 -C '\"http-bio-30011\"' -w 200 -c 50" }
```

but the result in the nrpe.cfg is

```
...-C http-bio-30011..
```

If I use ''\"http-bio-30011\"'' in the ansible script

the result in the nrpe.cfg is

```
...-C "http-bio-30011"...
```

How I can escaping the single quotes and the double quotes to get this `-C '"http-bio-30011"'`?

Greetings Georg

Comment: If answer helped you, it's good thing to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.

Answer (score 5):

It's a [bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/2227) in `lineinfile` module.

The correct syntax from YAML point of view is following (but it will work, only when bug is fixed). You should [escape](http://yaml.org/spec/current.html#id2532720) only two characters `"` and `\` in double-quoted literals:

```
line: "command[SERVICE_tomcat_Threads_pi]=/appiu/monitoring/check_tomcat_threads.pl -H localhost -p 30011 -C '\"http-bio-30011\"' -w 200 -c 50"
```

To temporarily workaround it, you can use:

```
line: 'command[SERVICE_tomcat_Threads_pi]=/appiu/monitoring/check_tomcat_threads.pl -H localhost -p 30011 -C \''"http-bio-30011"\'' -w 200 -c 50'
```